# Referencing cross namespace services in microk8s

Tags: microk8s

If I have 2 namespaces A and B, attempting to reference a service from B using the standard DNS convention for k8s `<svc-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` fails

so from a a pod deployed in namespace B to reference db service deployed in namespace for example:

`dbservice.A.svc.cluster.local`

fails to resolve

Is there some additional configuration needed for the dns service to make this work ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can nslookup from a pod in the same namespace, but not from a different one. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Yes so it seems using [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) is the common way of doing this. If your service resides in namespace B for example and you want to reach it from A. You would create a service in A of **type: ExternalName** and then set the **externalName** to be the full svc name in B e.g. mysvc.B.svc.cluster.local

Comment: I had a second issue with this. I am using hostNetwork: true in the deployment, so the DNS resolution for names like *.svc.cluster.local was not possible until I added dnsPolicy: "ClusterFirstWithHostNet" to the deployment.